# Standard for Exception Handling

Tags: java, scala, exception

I am writing an API, which will return some response, of course. There is a chance of the exception. 
There are two options of response in the case of any exception:

1. Return some error message in response and let your consumers know what is going on.
2. Rather than error message return default response and don't let
   consumers know If something bad is going on.

I know both approaches has its own pros and cons.

I just want to know, which one is the better approach to adopt and why?

Comment: With no other information it is impossible to choose one option.  Either one or both could be valid but unless you provide a lot more detail on your objective the question is not answerable.

Comment: I can't really see many pros with just failing silently and not letting the user of your API know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API should never leave its users wondering why they are not getting the expected response.

Errors forwarded to the users should be of at least two kinds:

- errors due to invalid parameters passed to the API calls. This is an user error. If your API exposes HTTP, a 400 error is expected.
- (unexpected) errors that happened on the API server although the supplied parameters were correct. If your API exposes HTTP, a 500 error is expected.

For user (400) errors, the API should provide the maximum details on the error so that the user can correct its input.

For server (500) errors, this is up to you, but the more details, the easier support calls will be to answer. Since this is likely a bug, a stacktrace is a big help for a developer to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Return some error message in response and let your consumers know what is going on.**

You should try to extend the `Exception` class and define your own Exception Codes and then throw this custom exception object instead of `SQLException` or `DataAccessExceptions`.

Later you can also provide a basic manual for troubleshooting the errors based on the custom codes you defined.

It is a bad idea to show the SQL Trace/Exception to the end user as it may reveal some important information about your application such as SQL Queries, DB Schema and Table Names etc.

**2. Rather than error message return default response and don't let consumers know If something bad is going on.**

This is not a recommended approach as it will leave the users in state of a mystery of what's going wrong with the API and what they can do to fix it.